# How to hide cytoscape nodes when graph is ready/rendered?

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I want to hide all the successors of the parent when the graph renders and show when tapped. But the code I have shows the nodes in the beginning and hides/shows when I tap the parent(got it from another question posted here).

```
var parentArray = ["2", "6", "8", "9"];

for(var i=0; i < parentArray.length; ++i) {
    cy.on('tap', '[id = \"' + parentArray[i] + '\"]' , function() {
        if (this.scratch().restData == null) {
            this.scratch({
                restData: this.successors().targets().remove()
            });                    
        } else {
            this.scratch().restData.restore();
            this.scratch({
                estData: null
            });
        }
    });
}
```

How do I hide all the successors in the beginning?

Comment: try changing visibility instead of removing them

Comment: @canbax I implemented the visibility changing version. But now the issue is, when the edges don't go. I also tried display setting. But when the graph goes out of the viewport when I make it display:element. Any way to rerender the layout?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean by "But now the issue is, when the edges don't go"

Comment: @canbax as in only the nodes will disappear but the edges towards the invisible nodes are still present

Comment: Hmm, I see. You might try using an extension for hiding and showing elements. https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-view-utilities

Answer (score 2):

If you use classes, you don't have to remove the nodes. I used a dagre graph with 3 DAGs, in the cy.ready callback, I defined some parent nodes and added the hidden class to all of their successors. Later, you just have to remove that class to display the graph again, though the layout may need to be rerun, not sure about that. Here is my code:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px",
        "border-color": "black",
        "border-opacity": "1",
        "border-width": "10px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "$node > node",
      css: {
        "padding-top": "10px",
        "padding-left": "10px",
        "padding-bottom": "10px",
        "padding-right": "10px",
        "text-valign": "top",
        "text-halign": "center",
        "background-color": "#bbb"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ":selected",
      css: {
        "background-color": "black",
        "line-color": "black",
        "target-arrow-color": "black",
        "source-arrow-color": "black"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ".hidden",
      css: {
        "display": "none"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "n0"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n7"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n11"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n12"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n15"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n16"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "n0",
          target: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n3"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n2",
          target: "n7"
        }
      },
      //{ data: { source: "n2", target: "n11" } },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n2",
          target: "n16"
        }
      },
      //{ data: { source: "n3", target: "n4" } },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n3",
          target: "n16"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n4",
          target: "n5"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n4",
          target: "n6"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n6",
          target: "n8"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n8",
          target: "n9"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n8",
          target: "n10"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n11",
          target: "n12"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n12",
          target: "n13"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n13",
          target: "n14"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n13",
          target: "n15"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "dagre",
    padding: 5
  }
}));

cy.ready(function() {
  let parentNodeIds = ['n0', 'n4', 'n11']
  for (id in parentNodeIds) {
    cy.nodes(`#${parentNodeIds[id]}`).successors().targets().classes('hidden')
  }
})

cy.off("click");
cy.on("click", function() {
  cy.$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden')
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a good solution and I had actually tried this before. The problem I had with this was when I change to display:element, the nodes rendered outside the viewport. I got a solution and its similar to yours. I am going to post that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting fact

There are also methods `hide()` and `show()` which are not mentioned in the docs but exist in [the code](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/unstable/src/collection/style.js#L267) for at least six years. These methods change element's or collection's `display` property.

```js
  show: function(){
    this.css( 'display', 'element' );
    return this; // chaining
  },

  hide: function(){
    this.css( 'display', 'none' );
    return this; // chaining
  },
```

Here is the example, that actually works and hides all elements with class `someclass`:

```js
cy.$('.someclass').hide()
```